# Using the Present Perfect after the preposition "after" in an adverbial clause

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect, adverbials

> That's basic critical thinking. But how can a critic, writing about his own encounter with the work, be responsible for unpredictable
> emotional responses in individual readers? But, as Scott says, this is
> not a progressive kindergarten where everybody gets points for trying.
> You do work in public - and that includes the reviews that Scott and
> other critics write - and you open yourself to criticism. What
> alternative are you suggesting? (" If you can't say something nice...
> "?) Scott's example was about somebody reading the review before the
> fact; **I have often used examples of people reading a review after
> they've already had their own experience with the movie.** Yes, you
> might feel hurt that somebody else didn't feel the same way you did.
> But critics don't have time machines, and even if they did, what would
> hypothetically possible retrospective spoilage have to do with the
> validity or invalidity of the criticism?​

Source:
A.O. Scott on criticism: THIS IS NOT A PROGRESSIVE KINDERGARTEN

> If you say that someone **has closed or shut the stable door after the horse has bolted**, you mean that they have tried to prevent something
> happening but they have done so too late to prevent damage being
> done.

Source: [to close the stable door after the horse has bolted](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-close-the-stable-door-after-the-horse-has-bolted)

I've learned that prepositions *"after"* and *"before"* are used with the Past Simple or the Past Perfect when referring to the past, so why is the Present Perfect used in these example sentences?

Is it because the speaker/writer wants to *emphasize* that *both* actions are still relevant in the present?

Comment: "I've learned that prepositions "after" and "before" are used with the Past Simple or the Past Perfect when referring to the past" Where have you learnt that? Are you sure it applied to every situation, or just some (e.g. in past-tense narratives)? As your examples show, it's common to use present perfect.

Comment: @Stuart F I've learned it from various grammar books and English learning websites that when talking about the past _(e.g. in past-tense narratives)_ as you said, we use the Past Simple with _"after"_ and _"before"_ because it refers to a _specific time period_ which the Present Perfect doesn't provide. That's why I'm asking this question because I don't know when to use the Present Perfect instead of the Past Simple after _"after"_ or _"before"_.

Comment: @Stuart F That means: _I have often used examples of people reading a review after **they already had** their own experience with the movie._ and _If you say that someone has closed or shut the stable door after the **horse bolted**..._ should be instead.

Comment: It feels so natural to a native speaker that it's hard to explain. I think the point is that these are 'typical' situations rather than actual past events. The critic is talking about _examples of people reading a review after they have seen the film_, not _a particular person who read a review after he had seen the film_. It's normal to use the present perfect in these cases.

Comment: The chronology is complex in the sentence "I have often used examples of people reading a review after they've already had their own experience with the movie". You have three events: the use of the example, reading the review, and having their experience. So simple rules may not apply. When you have only two events, generally you'd use present in the after-clause ("I'll give him the book after he arrives") or simple past ("I gave him the book after he arrived") or less commonly past perfect. But perfect may be used in particular situations that a grammar book is unlikely to fully enumerate.

Comment: "If you say that someone has closed or shut the stable door after the horse has bolted" also has three points in time, and a hypothetical, and it is quoting the standard expression "shut the stable door after the horse has bolted". Which explains why it is using the present perfect. Simple grammar rules work in simple situations.

Comment: Although that then raises the question of why "to shut the stable door after the horse has bolted" is correct. And I think the OP is correct that it's "because the speaker/writer wants to emphasize that both actions are still relevant in the present", and in particular because you have the infinitive "to shut".

Comment: What could people reading reviews after they've already 'had their own experience' have to do with using the Present Perfect after any preposition in any adverbial clause?

Come to that, what difference do you see between 'had their own experience with…' and simply 'seen…' the movie?